# Can Linq be prevented from casting a value in the where clause of the SQL?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to replicate the following query using LINQ:

```
select p_id, sum(pct_ownership)
from owner 
where PCT_OWNERSHIP is not null
  and status = N'O'
group by p_id 
having sum(pct_ownership) > 100
```

The Linq expression I've created is as follows:

```
From p In context.Owner
Where p.Status = "O" And p.Pct_Ownership IsNot Nothing
Group By pid = p.P_Id Into pct = Sum(p.Pct_Ownership)
Where pct > 100
Select pct, pid
```

This is the SQL produced by the LINQ expression:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [P_Id], 
    CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS real) AS [C1]
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Extent1].[P_Id] AS [K1], 
         SUM([Extent1].[Pct_Ownership]) AS [A1]
     FROM 
         [dbo].[Owner] AS [Extent1]
     WHERE 
         (N'O' = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ([Extent1].[Pct_Ownership] IS NOT NULL)
     GROUP BY 
         [Extent1].[P_Id]) AS [GroupBy1]
WHERE  
    CAST( [GroupBy1].[A1] AS real) > cast(100 as real)
```

When comparing my original query results to those produced by the linq expression, it looks like the casting is removing some of the results.

My guess is that the cast is rounding the Sum(Pct_Ownership) value due to some precision issue (which is strange, because the original value is stored as a real).

Is there a way to prevent linq from casting values in where clause of the query?

Comment: Well, `Sum` will return the sum of reals as a float, that may be part of the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql

Comment: e.g. `SELECT CAST(100.000001 as real), CAST(100.000001 as float)` -> `100, 100.000001`

Comment: @BurnsBA If it were stored in the db as a float, I'd agree with you.  But it's stored as a real, so it would seem strange that a real value, converted to a float would have a different value when once again converted back to a real .  If I remove the cast on the A1 column of the outer query, the expected results are returned, so it seems that the culprit is the cast to real, not the sum.

Comment: What if you do `Where pct > CType(100, Single)`?

Comment: Try with 100f maybe will not be cast

Comment: @Rolan this is a precision/significant digit issue and not unexpected. Not every decimal number can be stored as binary, and the problem is compounded with less storage like `real` (this is what `decimal` type helps address). See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cd394/3 for some examples of precision errors. For your issue, even if you don't cast back to `real` you will probably still get results other than what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @BurnsBA, you're spot on.